# Using 2 Dispatcher Timer at different times in Windows Store Application with C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, dispatchertimer

I want a MediaElement application. I want to pause MediaElement with this application at specified times. Theorically, I should use 2 DispatcherTimer for this. I am using a DispatcherTimer for pause but second timer does not run. Is there any problem with my codes ?Here is my code. Thanks inadvance

```
static DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer, dispatcherTimer2;
        private void MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((MediaElement)sender).CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {

                tbMessage.Text = "playing";
                dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
                dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                dispatcherTimer.Start();

                dispatcherTimer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
                dispatcherTimer2.Tick += dispatcherTimer2_Tick;
                dispatcherTimer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                dispatcherTimer2.Start();
            }
        }

        void dispatcherTimer2_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {

            tb2.Text = dispatcherTimer2.Interval.Seconds.ToString();
            if (dispatcherTimer2.Interval.Seconds == 12)
            {
                mp.Play();
                //dispatcherTimer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {

            // Updating the Label which displays the current second
            tbMessage.Text = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
            tbMessage.Text = mp.Position.Seconds.ToString() + " " + dispatcherTimer.Interval.Seconds.ToString();
            if (mp.Position.Seconds == 3)
            {
                mp.Pause();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatcherTimer2.Interval.Seconds
```

is the **time between ticks**
since this is 1 second and not 12, the if statement will always be false

you can try this instead:

```
int ticks = 0;
void dispatcherTimer2_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            ticks++;
            tb2.Text = ticks.ToString();
            if (ticks == 12)
            {
                mp.Play();
                //dispatcherTimer.Start();

                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
```

or something like that

Comment: I did it but this time, ticks increases as +2  and video does not play. Strange .. I did not understand why ?

Comment: @SilverSharK . at my pc, it works perfectly. i don't know how it's possible it increases as +2.

Comment: Yes, I am too.. I am using a dispatcher timer at now but it increases as +2. So, is there any issue with windows store app ?

Comment: is it possible to use a normal timer? or does it really need to be a dispatchertimer? @SilverSharK

Comment: @SilverSharK wait, is the 'ticks' int increasing as +2?

Comment: Yes, ticks int increasing as +2. But I think that I solved with using a bool flag. I am testing at now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question with following solution. Maybe it can be asist to someone.

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

            int QuestionCount = AppConfiguration.QuestionList.allsecs.Split('-').Length;
            QuestionTimes = new int[QuestionCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < QuestionTimes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (AppConfiguration.QuestionList.allsecs.Split('-')[i] != null && AppConfiguration.QuestionList.allsecs.Split('-')[i] != "")
                {
                    QuestionTimes[i] = Convert.ToInt32(AppConfiguration.QuestionList.allsecs.Split('-')[i]);
                }
            }

            string QuestionVideoLink = AppConfiguration.QuestionList.VideoLink;
            VideoPlayer.Source = new Uri(AppConfiguration.TestVideoLink + QuestionVideoLink, UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        static bool flag = false;

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            count++;
            tbMessage.Text = count.ToString();

                //tbMessage.Text = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
                //tbMessage.Text = mp.Position.Seconds.ToString() + " " + dispatcherTimer.Interval.Seconds.ToString();
                if (sn.Contains(mp.Position.Seconds) && !flag)
                {
                    mp.Pause();
                    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
                    tbDenemeSoru.Text = "Deneme Soru 1";
                    tbMessage.Text = "Video Durdu";
                    pnlProgressBar.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
                    count = 0;
                }
                if (sn.Contains(mp.Position.Seconds) && !flag)
                {
                    mp.Pause();
                    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
                    tbDenemeSoru.Text = "Deneme Soru 2";
                    tbMessage.Text = "Video Durdu";
                    pnlProgressBar.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (mp.Position.Seconds > 3 && count == 0)
                {
                    flag = true;
                }


            // Updating the Label which displays the current second

            // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
            //CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pnlProgressBar.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            mp.Play();
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
            flag = false;
        }
```